# Can't able to create table in magento 1 upgrade script

Tags: magento-1.9, database, upgrade-script

I am trying to create a **script** to **create a table in my custom module**. I tried many method but i thing there is a minor issue in my script. I want sure what is mistake.

**Config file**

**Path - app\code\community\Amit\Custommodule\etc\config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
   <modules>
      <Amit_Custommodule>
         <version>1.1.0</version>
      </Amit_Custommodule>
   </modules>
 <global>
<models>
    <custommodule>
        <class>Amit_Custommodule_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>custommodule_resource</resourceModel>
    </custommodule>
    <custommodule_resource>
        <entities>
            <custommodule>
                <table>custommodule</table>
            </custommodule>
            <custommodule>
                <table>custommodule2</table>
            </custommodule>             
            <custommodule>
                <table>custommodule3</table>
            </custommodule>
        </entities>
    </custommodule_resource>
</models>
<resources>
    <custommodule_setup>
        <setup>
            <module>Amit_Custommodule</module>
            <class>Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
        </setup>
        <connection>
            <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
    </custommodule_setup>
    <custommodule_read>
        <connection>
            <use>core_read</use>
        </connection>
    </custommodule_read>
    <custommodule_write>
        <connection>
            <use>core_write</use>
        </connection>
    </custommodule_write>
</resources>
<!-- start of block -->
<blocks>
    <custommodule>
        <class>Amit_Custommodule_Block</class>
    </custommodule>
</blocks>
```

standard
            
                Amit_Custommodule
                custommodule
            
        
    
    
        
            
                custommodule.xml
            
        
    
 
**Sql Query**

**Path - app\code\community\Amit\Custommodule\sql\custommodule_setup\upgrade-1.0.0-1.1.0.php**

```
<?php
$installer=$this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->run("
-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable('custommodule3')};
CREATE TABLE {$this->getTable('custommodule3')} (
  `custommodule_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment COMMENT 'Q&A ID',
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL  COMMENT 'Product Id' ,
  `customer_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Customer Name',
  `customer_email` varchar(255) NOT NULL  COMMENT 'Customer Email',
  `question` text NOT NULL  COMMENT 'Question',
  `answer` text NOT NULL  COMMENT 'Answer',
  `status` smallint(6) NOT NULL default '0' COMMENT 'Status',
  `created_time` datetime NULL,
  `update_time` datetime NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`custommodule_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    ");
$installer->endSetup();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `config.xml` change below code

```
<models>
    <custommodule>
    <class>Amit_Custommodule_Model</class>
    <resourceModel>custommodule_resource</resourceModel>
    </custommodule>
    <custommodule_resource>
    <entities>
        <custommoduleone>
            <table>custommodule</table>
        </custommoduleone>
        <custommoduletwo>
            <table>custommodule2</table>
        </custommoduletwo>             
        <custommodulethree>
            <table>custommodule3</table>
        </custommodulethree>
    </entities>
    </custommodule_resource>
</models>
```

and in your `upgrade-1.0.0-1.1.0.php`

change `getTable` param

```
$this->getTable('custommodule/custommodulethree');
```